# Simplification and "average" of polytopes

Tags: algorithms, polytopes

I have multiple (convex and bounded) polytopes, all of them describing the feasible area of a given LP (the rest of the LP is always the same), for a number of scenarios. Since those polytopes are too complex I'm looking to

(a) simplify them (e.g. transforming a polytope defined by $n$ constraints to one with $m << n$ constraints), and

(b) aggregate them by finding a representative "average" (or "median") polytope.

---

For (a) I assume that some kind of either "smallest" convex hull, or "largest" convex polytope, with $m$ constraints could work (?).

For (b) I'm kind of lost, on what a reasonable approach would be (side-note: it can be assumed that most of the polytopes to be aggregated overlap, and many also by quite some volume).

Are there any algorithms out there that I could check out? Since I'm dealing with **a lot** of really high-dimensional polytopes I'm looking for something that works in practice (and not necessarily has to be "exact").

Comment: Your question is rather abstract and hard to answer without further details. E.g. would an over-approximation count as a simplification in your setting? What exactly are the requirements on your "average" polytope, and how should this average aggregate the given polytopes?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand what you mean with "over-approximation". But, yes, I think so: assuming the original polytopes has $v$ vertices, a larger polytope, that completely covers the original one and has less than $v$ vertices would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Perhaps template polyhedra could help you, see https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-78800-3_14. As all inequalities are fixed expressions with varying constant terms some kind of "average" could be defined over the constant terms in a reasonable way.

Comment: Regarding the average: for simplicity let's assume I'm looking at polygons representing the feasible area in $x/y$ plane. The polygons are overlapping (like drawing a lot of ellipses over each other, each one a bit different, but with similar centres). I'm looking for one that kind of represents those, e.g. the smallest that contains x% of all polygons, or...?

Comment: Thanks for the link! As far as I understand that only considers polytopes ($i \in I$) where $a \cdot x <= b_i$, but mine can have varying $a_i$ for each polytope.

Comment: Just define a fixed set of directions $a_i$, $ i\in I$ beforehand and use this template to over-approximate your given polygons. (I.e. solve LPs to determine the proper constant terms). A very simple template polyhedron is a rectangular box, that has only 2d constraints where d is the dimension of the space you consider. But more complex shapes are possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145520/discussion-between-willem-hagemann-and-kchnkrml).

Comment: How are the polytopes defined? A convex hull of points or a collection of inequalities?

Comment: @copper.hat I have them as inequalities, but could of course (with some computational effort) convert them to vertex representation.